How to load env vars from .env before running C# tests through VS Code
I am trying to get rid of the .runsettings file which I have in my project repo and keep all my config variables in a single .env file.
The one place where I am stuck in is in the scenario when running tests through VS Code. I am writing C# and using the C# Dev Kit / C# extensions (Linux OS). There extensions automatically detect the NUnit tests and display them in the tests window. I can click the "Run Tests" and all the tests are executed. The problem is that the only way I found how to supply environment variables to these test runs is setting the dotnet.unitTests.runSettingsPath configuration option to the location of the .runsettings file. I dont want to keep this .runsettings file around just for this one functionality. How can I tell VS Code to load the environment variables from a .env file when I trigger the "Run Tests" functionality.
Just in case anyone asks, I do not have a special task in my tasks.json or special entry in my launch.json files for the test run. It looks like VS Code is smart enough to automatically figure out how to find, load and run the tests in my project.

You can manually add environment variables using Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("YOUR_VARIABLE","the_value");
This means that you can initialize your tests to load and parse a .env file so that you can read them using Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(key).
If you are using Configuration, there is cross compatibility if you name your .env variables using __ for hierarchical settings.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-8.0#naming-of-environment-variables

I faced the same problem today and my solution looks like this:

Created a test.env file at the test project's root folder with the environment variables needed to run my tests. (Optional: added it to my .gitignore to avoid versioning the file as each developer has their own values)
Instructed .NET to copy the env file to the output directory (e.g., bin/Debug/net8.0) by adding the following lines to the MyProject.Tests.csproj file:

<ItemGroup>
  <Content Include="*.env">
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  </Content>
</ItemGroup>


Added a reference to the dotenv.net Nuget package in my test project. More information on how to do that can be found in the Nuget page.
Loaded the env file in my test class using the following lines (SetUp is an annotation from the NUnit package. You may need a different annotation if you are using other test framework like xUnit):

private const string ENV_FILE = "test.env";

[SetUp]
public void SetUp()
{
    if (File.Exists(ENV_FILE))
    {
        DotEnv.Load(options: new DotEnvOptions(envFilePaths: [ENV_FILE]));
    }
}

